# What is the HTML for="" attribute in <label>?

Tags: html

I have seen this in jQuery - what does it do?

```
<label for="name"> text </label>
<input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
```

Comment: Where have you seen this in jQuery?

Comment: May be in some of inline styles of jquery. Many of the jquery's use this to define the requirement in the html page

Comment: the above line is not a part of jquery its html

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To associate the `<label>` with an `<input>` element, you need to give the `<input>` an `id` attribute. The `<label>` then needs a `for` attribute whose `value` is the same as the input's `id`:

```
<label for="username">Click me</label>
<input type="text" id="username">
```

The `for` attribute associates a `<label>` with an `<input>` element; which offers some major advantages:
1. The label text is not only visually associated with its corresponding text input; it is programmatically associated with it too. This means that, for example, a screen reader will read out the label when the user is focused on the form input, making it easier for an assistive technology user to understand what data should be entered.
2. You can **click the associated label** to focus/activate the input, as well as the input itself. This **increased hit area** provides an advantage to anyone trying to activate the input, including those using a touch-screen device.

**Alternatively**, you can nest the `<input>` directly inside the `<label>`, in which case the `for` and `id` attributes are not needed because the association is implicit:

```
<label>Click me <input type="text"></label>
```

Notes:
One `input` can be associated with multiple labels.
When a `<label>` is clicked or tapped and it is associated with a form control, the resulting click event is also raised for the associated control.

### Accessibility concerns

Don't place interactive elements such as anchors or buttons inside a label. Doing so, makes it difficult for people to activate the form input associated with the label.

#### Headings

Placing heading elements within a `<label>` interferes with many kinds of assistive technology, because headings are commonly used as a navigation aid. If the label's text needs to be adjusted visually, use CSS classes applied to the `<label>` element instead.
If a form, or a section of a form needs a title, use the `<legend>` element placed within a `<fieldset>`.

#### Buttons

An `<input>` element with a `type="button"` declaration and a valid value attribute does not need a label associated with it. Doing so may actually interfere with how assistive technology parses the button input. The same applies for the `<button>` element.

Ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 191):

The `for` attribute is used in labels. It refers to the id of the element this label is associated with.

For example:

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
```

Now when the user clicks with the mouse on the `username` text the browser will automatically put the focus in the corresponding `input` field. This also works with other input elements such as `<textbox>` and `<select>`.

Quote from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1):

> This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with
>   another control. When present, the value of this attribute must be the
>   same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the
>   same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with
>   the element's contents.

As far as why your question is tagged with jQuery and where did you see it being used in jQuery I cannot answer because you didn't provide much information.

Maybe it was used in a jQuery selector to find the corresponding input element given a label instance:

```
var label = $('label');
label.each(function() {
    // get the corresponding input element of the label:
    var input = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
});
```

Comment: Just a side note. It is also used for the new `<output>` element. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/output).

Answer (score 14):

I feel the need to answer this. I had the same confusion.

```html
<p>Click on one of the text labels to toggle the related control:</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="female">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I changed the for attribute on the 'male' label to female. Now, if you click 'male' the 'female' radio will get checked.

Simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

a fast example:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input id="name" type="text" />
```

the `for=""` tag let focus the input when you click the label as well.

Answer (score 5):

You use it with labels to say that two objects belong together.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="rememberbox"/>
<label for="rememberbox">Remember your details?</label>
```

This also means that clicking on that label will change the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

it is used for `<label>` element

it is used with input type checkbox or redio to select on label click

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfbn5/)

Answer (score 3):

The `for` attribute of the `<label>` tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together.

Answer (score 3):

FYI - if you are in an typescript environment with e.g.

```
<label for={this.props.inputId}>{this.props.label}</label>
```

you need to use htmlFor

```
<label htmlFor={this.props.inputId}>{this.props.label}</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

It associates the label with an input element. HTML tags are meant to convey special meaning to users of various categories. Here is what label is meant for:

1. **For people with motor disabilities (also for general mouse users)**: Correctly used label tags can be clicked to access the associated form control. Eg. Instead of particularly clicking the checkbox, user can click on more easily clickable label and toggle the checkbox.
2. **For visually-challenged users**: Visually challenged users use screen-readers that reads the associated label tag whenever a form control is focused. It helps users to know the label which was otherwise invisible to them.

More about labelling -> https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when you call a jsx element inside itself.
Like so:

```
const Element = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Element />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Element;
```

Answer (score -1):

it is used in `<label>` text for html

eg.

```
<label for="male">Male</label>

<input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br>
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question, the OP didn't ask on how it is use ?

Answer (score -3):

It's the attribute for `<label>` tag : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: errr... we know that.