# What is 'for' used for in bootstrap form label?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know the meaning of `for="inputEmail3"`, seems its same as id, what is it for? Can I just remove `for="inputEmail3"` ?

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894169/what-is-the-html-for-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "for" attribute do in HTML <label> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432376/what-does-for-attribute-do-in-html-label-tag)

Comment: I thought its a bootstrap feature :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the HTML for="" attribute in <label>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894169/what-is-the-html-for-attribute-in-label)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you click on the label with your mouse, then the cursor will automagically jump to the input specified in the 'for' attribute. It's really useful, don't remove it.

Answer (score 3):

`for` specifies the element id to which the label belongs.

Comment: Which explains it's purpose in HTML. But question specifically asks for the purpose in Bootstrap.