# What is the HTML "for" attribute in <output> tag?

Tags: html

I can't understand for what `for` attribute in HTML5 new **output** tag, because result does not change depending on the presence of this attribute.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894169/what-is-the-html-for-attribute) was asked in the year 2012 (HTML4), HTML5 appeared in 2014 and my question is not duplicate. Answer why attr "for" is in HTML4.

Comment: For example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_output

Comment: @L_Church No, this is not true. Yes, it is a for attribute, but it is not the same as the one used on label.

Comment: whatever you say bud but quite a few agree with me here...

Comment: So truth on side of majority, not docs and logic?

Comment: @rangergref I don't know if it's the same answer or not for both, but I've highlighted the differences in the two questions and I voted to re-open.

Comment: @Cœur Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `for` attribute specifies the relationship between the result of the calculation, and the elements used in the calculation. See [MDN on `label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), [MDN on `output`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) and [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp).

### Examples

#### `label` tag

```html
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
```

#### `output` tag

```html
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">0
  <input type="range" id="a" value="50">100 +
  <input type="number" id="b" value="50"> =
  <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

Now when the user clicks with the mouse on the username text the browser will automatically put the focus in the corresponding input field. This also works with other input elements such as `<textbox>` and `<select>` and `<output>`.

Comment: In tag "label" it works as u explain, but in "output" it works smth else.

Comment: Just a element id. It specifies the relationship between the two id's. For ex: I'm just adding the  two values and i need to store it  in the result. I need to know,for what are the values are added up and stored.

Comment: A list of IDs of other elements, indicating that those elements contributed input values to (or otherwise affected) the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

As Mozilla Developer Network states:

> A list of IDs of other elements, indicating that those elements contributed input values to (or otherwise affected) the calculation.

So it is just a list which could be used for semantic purposes.

W3schools does not offer a sufficient explanation about the `for` tag. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) instead.

Answer (score 1):

It don't do anything much **it's just for getting better understanding about relationship among the inputs** whom output is associated.

So other's can understand your code easily.

> Refer below  : It's same without **for="x y"** inside output.

```html
<form oninput="z.value=parseInt(x.value)+parseInt(y.value)">
<label>First Value</label>
<input type="number" id="x" >
<label>Second Value</label>
<input type="number" id="y">
<label>Result :</label>
<output name="z"></output>
</form>
```