# How to give checkbox a border on click with css

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to make a checkbox I made into a button highlight its border and background on click but its not working.[image]

This is what is happening
[image]

and this is my code

```
<div id="ck-button">
                  <label id="label">
                    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                    <span className="title">Respirators</span>
                    <span className="description">
                      Surgical N95 or equivalent
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>
```

css

```
#ck-button label {
  width: 85%;
  border: 2px solid #eaf2fd;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
}

#ck-button label span {
  padding: 3px 0px;
}
#ck-button .title {
  color: #304256;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#ck-button .description {
  color: #6984a3;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 7px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked + span {
  color: #2f80ed;
}

#ck-button input:checked ~ #label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I've also tried this but it's not working

```
#ck-button input:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: As long as `<label>` is a parent of `<input>`, you will have no luck. The `<input>`-status can only affect siblings and descendants.

Comment: well the label is the parent so you can not nest it like that and there is no css rule to change parent. The checkbox would have to be `<input id="x" type="checkbox"/><label for"x"></label>`

Comment: to lay the input as a sibbling before the label, you have to use the attribute `for` to link them.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894169/what-is-the-html-for-attribute-in-label

Comment: Have you look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642335/9620269

Comment: @adoga-patricia you can also try this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/049gvzao/)