# Using the for attribute on an element other than the label

Tags: html

What if I want to use the `for` attribute on an element other than a `<label>`? Is this valid HTML? For example:

```
<div class="feedback" for="my-input-box"></div>
```

The idea is, I can use JavaScript to get the feedback container for an input using its ID. Like so:

```
var feedbackContainer = document.querySelector("[for='" + myInputBoxID + "']'");
```

I just want to know if this is valid HTML or not. If not, I can obviously just go for `data-for="..."` instead.

Comment: Is it not working, or are you receiving errors?

Comment: related (but not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/12894169/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML `for` attribute is only valid on `label` and `output` elements.

See - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp

So to answer your question, that is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

That is not valid HTML.

See on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp) that the `for=""` attribute only is used on `<label>` and `<output>`.